# How to count amount of values in a database using jinja and python

Tags: python, database, jinja2

I have a database where i save sessions in my flask app using python. For every session the database saves the persons name and other information. Now i want to use either jinja2 or a function in python to count how many times a person has had a session. So lets say the database contains the following info:

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | today |
| Bob | yesterday |
| Bob | yesterday |
| Linda | yesterday |

I want to be able to calculate and display the next table in my flask application:

| Name | Sessions |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 3 |
| Linda | 1 |

How do i do this?

Comment: Make a column name session in table when the person login add 1 to it.

Comment: Its not really a login, but a field where you can submit your name. So i want to count the amount of times the same name is in the database and show it

Comment: What kind of database? If it's a SQL database, you can run `SELECT name, COUNT(*) as session_count FROM sessions GROUP BY name`.

Comment: Its a SQLAlchemy database, would your solution still be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Linda'],
        'Date':['today', 'yesterday', 'yesterday', 'yesterday']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_result=df.groupby(['Name']).count().rename(columns={'Date': 'Sessions'})
df_result
```

Comment: This works, but the data is saved as a database and i tried changing it to: data = statistics.db but that didn't work. Also how do i display the table/results in my flask application using jinja?